Relation between running time of Insertion sort and number of inversions

What is the relationship between the running time of insertion sort and the number of inversions in the input array? Justify your answer.

Consider Insertion sort
Insertion-Sort(A, n):
    for i=2 to n
        key = A[i]
        j = i -1
        while j > 0 and A[j] > key
            A[j+1] = A[j]
            j=j-1
        A[j+1] = key

From the analysis given in the CLRS book the for loop runs for $n$ times assuming 1 based indexing.
The while loop should run for $$\sum_{i = 2}^{n}t{_i} \tag{1}$$
The number of inversions increases only when we enter the body of the while loop.
Lets say the number of inversions is $I$ then we can say that
$$I = \sum_{i = 2}^{n}t{_i} - 1 \tag{2}$$
Now the general running time of insertion sort is given as
$$ T(n) = c_{1}n + c_{2}(n - 1) + c_{3}(n - 1) + c_{4}\sum_{i = 2} ^ {n}t_{i} + c_{5}\sum_{i = 2}^{n}t_{i} - 1 + c_{6}\sum_{i = 2}^{n}t_{i} - 1 + c_{7}\sum_{i = 2}^{n}t_{i} - 1 + c_{8}(n-1) \tag{3}
$$
Changing the summation on $c_{4}$ term we get
$$
T(n) = c_{1}n + c_{2}(n - 1) + c_{3}(n - 1) + c_{4}\sum_{i = 2} ^ {n}t_{i}-1 + 1 + c_{5}\sum_{i = 2}^{n}t_{i} - 1 + c_{6}\sum_{i = 2}^{n}t_{i} - 1 + c_{7}\sum_{i = 2}^{n}t_{i} - 1 + c_{8}(n-1) \tag{4}
$$
Substituting (2) in (4) and arranging all the $c_{x}n$ terms and $c_{x}$ terms we get
$$
T(n) = c_{9}n + c_{10}I + c_{11}
$$
Can this be considered an alternate solution to the given question? as opposed to the one on WalkmeCLRS
